# Is there a way to lazy load a Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby, puppet, autoload

I am using puppet, but a Ruby-only solution is also good.

Problem: My puppet custom provider ruby code has a require statement for a Gem that has not yet been installed:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip'
```

I include a dependency for that gem, but since the puppet user defined type won't compile, it never gets to the point where it can download and install the gem.

Here is how I intend to load the gem:

```
  package { 'rubyzip':
    ensure   => 'latest',
    provider => 'gem'
  }
```

I thought that I could use autoload to lazy load the rubyzip gem and dodge the problem; by the time the ruby code is executed, the gem will already be installed and no runtime error will occur.

Is it possible to autoload rubyzip? I tried, but get syntax errors. Not sure how to do it.
I tried this, since I need the Zip::File class:

```
module Zip
  autoload :File, 'C:\PROGRA~2\PUPPET~1\PUPPET~1\sys\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rubyzip-1.1.6\lib\zip.rb'
end
```

Here is the error:

```
C:/Progra~2/PUPPET~1/PUPPET~1/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip-1.1.6/lib/zip/file.rb:45:in `<module:Zip>': uninitialized constant Zip::File (NameError)
        from C:/Progra~2/PUPPET~1/PUPPET~1/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip-1.1.6/lib/zip/file.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Progra~2/PUPPET~1/PUPPET~1/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Progra~2/PUPPET~1/PUPPET~1/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/PROGRA~2/PUPPET~1/PUPPET~1/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip-1.1.6/lib/zip.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/paul.chernoch/Documents/puppet deployer/phx_deployer/puppet/modules/mirrored_directory/lib/puppet/provider/mirrored_directory/zip/zipinstall.rb:92:in `from_zip'
        from C:/Users/paul.chernoch/Documents/puppet deployer/phx_deployer/puppet/modules/mirrored_directory/lib/puppet/provider/mirrored_directory/zip/zipinstall.rb:254:in `differences'
        from C:/Users/paul.chernoch/Documents/puppet deployer/phx_deployer/puppet/modules/mirrored_directory/lib/puppet/provider/mirrored_directory/zip/zipinstall.rb:235:in `has_differences?
'
        from C:/Users/paul.chernoch/Documents/puppet deployer/phx_deployer/puppet/modules/mirrored_directory/lib/puppet/provider/mirrored_directory/zip/zipinstall.rb:485:in `<main>'
```

Note: 
I am also trying to use puppet run stages to force the creation of the rubyzip package before the next stage, but not sure how to use stages either or if they will work.

Comment: Have you tried just `autoload :Zip, 'zip'`? Or `autoload :'Zip::File', 'zip/file'` if you just need `Zip::File`?

Comment: I just tried the variations you suggest, but they give similar errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on an alternative way to solve the problem.
My puppet manifest is now two-phase. (You need to run puppet apply twice. I did not use puppet run stages, as that did not work.)

1) Perform the first part of the installation, that does not require unzipping of files. This first part includes installing the rubyzip gem.

2) Perform the second part of the installation, which unzips files and copies them into their destination directories, plus performs and follow on steps.

This is accomplished by:

a) "confining" my provider to only be available on systems where the gem is installed.

b) Putting a rescue block around the place where I require the zip module.

Here is the confinement code that I added to my custom type provider logic:

```
  confine :true => begin
    begin
      require 'zip'
      true
    rescue LoadError
      false
    end
  end
```

Here is how I now require rubygems in my ruby module:

```
require 'rubygems'
begin
  require 'zip'
rescue LoadError
end
```

(Note: I tried to use custom features in my confinement logic, but it didn't work because of my ignorance of how to define them correctly.)

For the sake of helping other lost puppet amateurs (like myself), here is the whole provider ruby file, "zip.rb". Half the problem with the advice I read on the internet is that people give tiny snippets without context, and I invariably insert the code in the wrong place.

```
# Resource Type: mirrored_directory
# Provider:      zip
#
# Provides the interface between the Puppet custom resource type 'mirrored_directory'
# and the ruby class 'ZipInstall::Unzipper'.
# This permits missing or changed files to be extracted from a Zip archive on a Windows system,
# while unchanged files are left alone.
require 'rubygems'
require 'puppet/provider/mirrored_directory/zip/zipinstall'

Puppet::Type.type(:mirrored_directory).provide :zip do
  desc "Uses rubyzip to extract new or modified files from a zip archive on a Windows system."

  # Confine this provider to (a) Windows Systems where (b) the rubyzip gem is installed.
  confine :osfamily => :windows

  confine :true => begin
    begin
      require 'zip'
      true
    rescue LoadError
      false
    end
  end  

  defaultfor :osfamily => :windows

  include Puppet::Util::Warnings

  # The mirrored_directory resource exists iff the target directory exists.
  def exists?
    Puppet::FileSystem::File.exist?(@resource[:name])
  end

  # Assuming that the target directory is empty (or only contains excluded files),
  # extract all included files from the source archive and deposit them in the target directory
  # (or corresponding subdirectory).
  # Do not delete any files.
  def create
    Puppet::Util::Log.new(:level => :debug, :message => "create: About to unzip #{@resource[:source]}") 
    change_count = unzipper.extract(false)
    @property_hash[:ensure] = exists? ? :present : :absent
  end

  # Delete the contents of the target directory and subdirectories 
  # (other than those that are excluded).
  def destroy
    change_count = unzipper.delete
    @property_hash.clear
  end

  # Check if the files in the target directory match those in the source zip archive or not.
  def is_current
    Puppet::Util::Log.new(:level => :debug, :message => "is_current: About to examine #{@resource[:source]}") 
    !unzipper.has_differences?(false)
  end

  # Extract each file from the source archive that differs from the corresponding file
  # in the target directory. 
  # Optionally delete files found in the target directory but not in the source archive,
  # according to the parameter :do_deletes.
  def is_current=(value)
    unzipper_to_use = unzipper
    changes = unzipper_to_use.differences(false, false)
    count = unzipper_to_use.apply_changes(changes, @resource[:do_deletes])
    @property_hash[:is_current] = value
    0
  end

  # TODO: Search computer for all installed directories so that the installed 
  # mirrored_directory resource instances can be queried by puppet.
  def self.instances
    []
  end

  # Construct a new Unzipper, using these parameters supplied to the resource type:
  #   :source, :name, :exclude, :include
  # Supplies a logger that delegate to puppet's own logging.
  def unzipper
    # Puppet has numerous loggin levels, including:
    #    :crit, :err, :warning, :notice, :info, :debug
    logger = ->(level,message) {
      Puppet::Util::Log.new(:level => level, :message => message) 
    }
    ZipInstall::Unzipper.new(@resource[:source], @resource[:name], :prefix_depth => @resource[:prefix_depth], :exclude_files => @resource[:exclude], :include_files => @resource[:include], :logger => logger) 
  end

end
```

And here is the associated custom type file that uses the provider, mirrored_directory.rb:

```
Puppet::Type.newtype(:mirrored_directory) do
  desc 'mirrored_directory keeps a directory in sync with an archive by extracting new or changed files from the archive and/or deleting extraneous files from the directory.'
  ensurable

  newparam(:path, :namevar => true) do  
    desc 'path of the target root directory into which files will be extracted.'
    validate do |value|
      fail("Invalid path #{value}") unless Pathname.new(value).absolute?
    end
  end

  newparam(:source) do
    desc 'source path to the archive from which files will be extracted.'
    validate do |value|
      fail("Invalid path #{value}") unless Pathname.new(value).absolute?
    end
  end

  newparam(:prefix_depth) do
    desc 'Number of directory segments to remove from beginning of paths extracted from zip file.'
    defaultto 0
  end

  newparam(:exclude, :array_matching => :all) do
    desc 'List of wildcards that match target files that should NOT be updated or deleted.'
    defaultto []
  end

  newparam(:include, :array_matching => :all) do
    desc 'List of wildcards that match source files that MAY be extracted from the archive.'
    defaultto ['*']
  end

  newparam(:do_deletes) do
    desc 'Determines if files will be deleted or not when found in the target directory but not in the archive.'
    newvalues(:true, :yes, :false, :no)
    defaultto false
    validate { |arg| }
    munge do |value|
      newval = super(value)
      case newval
        when :true, :yes; true
        when :false, :no; false
        else
          self.fail "Invalid do_deletes value #{value.inspect} (expecting 'true' or 'false')"
      end
    end
  end

  newproperty(:is_current) do
    desc 'Indicates if the files in the target directory are consistent with those in the source archive.'
    newvalues(:true, :yes, :false, :no)
    defaultto true
    validate { |arg| }
    munge do |value|
      newval = super(value)
      case newval
        when :true, :yes; true
        when :false, :no; false
        else
          self.fail "Invalid is_current value #{value.inspect} (expecting 'true' or 'false')"
      end
    end
  end

  # Require that the source archive exist.
  autorequire(:file) { self[:source] if Pathname.new(self[:source]).absolute? }

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The main source of your issue is that you are deploying a custom fact from the `lib/` directory of a module.  This all happens in a part of Puppet called `pluginsync`, which is before any catalog code is parsed or acted on.  Basically it's:

`pluginsync` -> `upload facts` -> `return catalog` -> `execute`

So, no amount of puppet magic (stages, resource ordering, what-have-you) can address this problem.

I see two possibilities:

1)  Modify the Ruby code to rescue on the require 'zipfile' and set a dummy value for that fact like 'N/A' until the gem is available.  Update any Puppet code that depends on this fact to expect this behavior, of course, because the first Puppet run will always fail to have this fact.

2)  Modify your system bootstrapping/rollout process to ensure this gem is installed with Puppet in some other way.

Comment: My understanding of puppet facts is poor, so please clarify. I wrote a defined type called "mirrored_directory". It has a provider called "zip". I implement this custom provider in a file named "zip.rb", which includes a module I wrote (zipinstall) that is in a file named "zipinstall.rb". zipinstall.rb then tries to require rubyzip. You may be right about what my options are, but how does this have to do with facts? As far as I know, I have not created any custom facts.

Comment: Oh, I entirely brain failed when I read your question, I thought you had created a custom fact.  I think my answer still applies, because I believe custom types are sent and processed in pluginsync as well.  Pluginsync copies everything in lib/ directories of modules to the node and attempts to load it into Puppet (afaik).

Comment: Seems to be confirmed here https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html. Even with stages, Puppet attempts to the load the code only once. You could maybe accomplish the same thing with a type in that it does nothing when it can't require the gem, but that really goes against what Puppet is trying to do.  I think you need to bundle the gem into your Puppet distribution and upgrade your existing nodes.

Comment: Or what about embedding the source of rubyzip (or parts of it) into a module within your Ruby code?  You could ship the entire source with your module, as long as you made the modifications to namespace it properly, and the license allowed it.

Comment: The package is open source, so I could consider merging rubyzip into my code, though I'd prefer not to. But your mention of facts gives me an idea. What if I define a custom fact that checks if the gem is installed? Then I could use that fact to control how much installation I do. This would lead to a two-phase installation process. Is this doable?

Comment: It's certainly doable, but it would ruin the "running Puppet successfully means my server is Good" goal of Puppet.  If that's acceptable in your use-case, go for it.  I find the 'vendoring rubyzip' approach to be better overall.